# Turn off animation at runtime in angular

Tags: angular, animation

I understand I can use BrowserAnimationModule and NoopAnimationsModule when I bootstrap the application. What is the recommended way to turn off animation at run-time, if the user requests it for ADA and other reasons?

Answer (score 4):

There may be an elegant solution but this works as of angular 4.0.0:
(Disclaimer I found the basis for this code for 2.0)

In your app.module add these imports:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AnimationDriver, ɵWebAnimationsDriver } from '@angular/animations/browser';
```

Add this function:

```
export function animationFactory(): any {
  const noop = AnimationDriver.NOOP;
  const driver = new ɵWebAnimationsDriver();
  return {
    animate: (element: any, keyframes: {
        [key: string]: string | number;
    }[], duration: number, delay: number, easing: string, previousPlayers?: any[]) => {
      if (!wantToAnimate) {
        return noop.animate(element, keyframes, duration, delay, easing, previousPlayers);
      } else {
        return driver.animate(element, keyframes, duration, delay, easing, previousPlayers);
      }
    }
  };
};
```

import BrowserAnimationModule

```
imports: [
  ...,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
]
```

provide AnimationDriver, using the factory function above

```
providers: [
  ...,
  { provide: AnimationDriver, useFactory: animationFactory },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

kudos to @user2957238

Here is the package [ngx-no-animation-for-dinosaur](https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-no-animation-for-dinosaur) base on his idea.

I also add a simple browser detection feature.

So the animation will only be enabled on [supported browsers](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/blob/dev/docs/support.md#browser-support).

And you can also disable animation on all browsers thru config.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2RxkVjy1K3FgSxKycsEU?p=preview)

update :

Angular now provide `ɵNoopAnimationDriver`, so the original answer can be refactor as

```
 if (!isSupported) {
        return new ɵNoopAnimationDriver();
    } else {
        return new ɵWebAnimationsDriver();
    }
```